# Trying deploying a .NET Application in CICD

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-framework-version, aws-sdk-net

I am working on an application which is on .net framework , code is on github, 
Could someone help me regarding the buidspec.yml file and any extra files that needs to me in it 
i am using in project enviornment in CICD build project:

```
aws/codebuild/windows-base:2.0-19.11.15

buildspec.yml file
--------------------------------
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    SOLUTION: .\CSharpHelloWorld.sln
    PACKAGE_DIRECTORY: .\packages
    DOTNET_FRAMEWORK: 4.6.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - '& "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\NuGet.exe" restore $env:SOLUTION -PackagesDirectory $env:PACKAGE_DIRECTORY'
      - '& "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v$env:DOTNET_FRAMEWORK" $env:SOLUTION'
artifacts:
  files:
    - .\CSharpHelloWorld\bin\Debug\*
-------------------------------
```

while code build happens there is error like :

```
---------------------------
[Container] 2020/02/01 09:23:49 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2020/02/01 09:23:49 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: & "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v$env:DOTNET_FRAMEWORK" $env:SOLUTION. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2020/02/01 09:23:49 Entering phase POST_BUILD
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom docker image to build .Net framework applications see an example  here [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments-for-the-net-framework/][1]

The aws  build is  only for .NET core